# How hadoop client will know the location of the input datafile

Tags: hadoop

If I copyFromLocal a 200 MB file into HDFS, which portion of the file is placed in which block in which node? How can I know this?

In my scenario assume that the default block size is 64 MB.

Comment: The real question is why do you want to know it? By default a block size is really 64MB like you mentioned, but the distribution to the different nodes should be transparent to you, because reading the file from the HDFS is being done by the hdfs underlying service.

Comment: There is no option in "hadoop fs" command to get the block locations. FileSystem.getFileBlockLocations() function returns the block locations for the specified file. The BlockLocation contains "hosts" on which the blocks are stored. So, you can write your own program to find this out.

Comment: Thanks, in continuation to that above query: Suppose a 100 MB file is split between 2nodes and the 36 MB part present in 1 node dies, then the other 64MB datanode does not make sense to me. So can we identify such partial blocks? Is there a way to identify them? I know about hadoop dfsadmin <hdfs path> -blocks -files....

Comment: Any updates on my above query friends?

Comment: Do you have replication factor > 1? In that case, dead node data blocks can be read from other running node. Let's keep this handling  to Hadoop so that we can focus more on business logic instead of worrying on partition of data.

Comment: Am using a standalone pseudo distributed environment and replication factor is equal to 1, but still we need to know if there is a mechanism to figure out from where HDFS framework pulls the file from right?